# how to create a dictionary/list/class created from raw_input

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, vm-implementation

i'm very new to python, and i'm attempting to make a very rudimentary VM, with the ability to make and read "text files" (formatted strings).

now, there is going to be a command that allows the user to create a file. the file is stored as a class, but i am unsure how to do something like this -

```
def filecreate(filename,contents):
    filename = contents
filecreate(str(raw_input("File Name: ")), insertcontenthere)
```

upon attempting to do something like that in idle/pycharm, you can't, because it yells at you for the filename being undefined.

i've looked into the constructor functions, but i'm at a loss. the answer is likely obvious and i'm not seeing it, but i can't find it.

(and it's probably been answered, but because of the phrasing, i can't accurately search for it.)

Comment: Maybe you should explain in english what you want that code to actually do.

Comment: the user enters a command to make the file via raw_input, then the program makes a new object with the file class.

Comment: He needs a file system, that's all. he's trying to get user input for a filename then assign the contents of the file to that file name as a variable. He can do that, but needs a file system as a dictionary to store it in.

Comment: Adam Smith got it right. That's basically it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a file system somehow or another. If I may suggest something:

```
class FileSystem(dict):
    # I'm not really sure what you need a file system
    # to do specifically. Probably things like
    # FileSystem.listdir but this is kind of beyond the
    # scope of this question

fs = FileSystem()

def filecreate(filename,contents):
    global fs
    fs[filename] = contents

filecreate(str(raw_input("File Name: ")), insertcontenthere)
```

It may not be a bad idea to implement this all into the `FileSystem`, so you'll instead call `fs.filecreate(raw_input(), content)`. Also, you never need to call `str` on `raw_input` -- it will ALWAYS return a string.

Comment: actually, in reality, that'd be more "power-saving" and faster than making an new file class for every single one, right?

Comment: I'd make filecreate an instance method of FileSystem.

Comment: @dano I was just editing that in! Writing a file system without designing it first isn't exactly my forte! :)

Comment: @user3348394 I'd definitely suggest creating a `class File` that contains the relevant info as well. Store the `File` instance inside your `FileSystem` at the appropriate location and call it good.